# Visual Studio Team Services build with special character in file names

Tags: tfs, character-encoding, special-characters, azure-devops, tfsbuild

**EDIT**

Like suggested in the answers, i submitted this behavior to visual studio, and as a solution, i removed those special characters in the files name.

Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online) generated a build of the new version of my the solution, no problems in that. But i noticed that some files that i uploaded that have some special characters (ã,ç,õ), were generated with other characters, like "ç" changed to +º+.

We can't upload files with those characters? Or is some configuration that i am missing in the build configurations or elsewhere? Or some files with wrong encoding ? I uploaded .mp4 files and those special characters were changed as well.

Searched for this particular problem and only found problems with file name too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug.  You probably need to submit it on the UserVoice site:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't submit it with my account, so i asked a co-worker to submit it. If somebody else is interested, here is the [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2880887)